# Extract all text fields from individual nodes in XML

Tags: xml, xpath

Say I have an xml document and want to get all text nodes out of each bitl=.

```
<Stuff>
    <data>
        <Nodes>
            <NodeID>1</NodeID>
            <Name>thingA</Name>
            <MoreInfo>
                <Description>Scooter</Description>
            </MoreInfo>
        </Nodes>
        <Nodes>
            <NodeID>2</NodeID>
            <Name>thingB</Name>
            <MoreInfo>
                <Description>Bike</Description>
            </MoreInfo>
        </Nodes>
    </data>
</Stuff>
```

I want to extract the text from each one.

So I'd end up with: 1, thingA, Scooter; and 2, thingB, Bike.

```
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("Nodes", resultXml, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    logger.info("Evaluating: " + node.toString());

    // How do I get just the text nodes descending from the "node" I just found,
    // without knowing what the actual node names? I wan't this to work 
    // for any list of nodes, no matter what the sub-element names are.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With XPath to select all non white space text nodes I would simply use the path `//text()[normalize-space()]`, then you could iterate over the text nodes and access each node value using `node.getNodeValue()` or `node.getTextContent()`.

Comment: I did "NodeList fieldNodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//text()[normalize-space()]", node);" and printed out the content of each node I found. When evaluating a node, it would print out multiple copies of a random field, found elsewhere in the file.

Comment: Evaluating: <Nodes><NodeID>1</NodeID><Name>thingA</Name><MoreInfo><Description>Scooter</Description></MoreInfo></Nodes>
Found 12 field nodes.
thingyB
thingyB
thingyB
thingyB
thingyB
...

Comment: No, my suggestion is to use `NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//text()[normalize-space()]", resultXml, XPathConstants.NODESET);` instead of `NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("Nodes", resultXml, XPathConstants.NODESET);`. Or perhaps `NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//Nodes//text()[normalize-space()]", resultXml, XPathConstants.NODESET);`. And then you don't need a further evaluate, you can simply access the nodes in the selected NodeList/node set.